# LINQ C# complex nesting structure

Tags: c#, linq

I managed to make a selection from the complex structure of the object, but only with the help of foreach, how can I avoid this foreach and solve my problem, just using LINQ?

```
        var product = new List<ProductCrp>
        {
            new ProductCrp {
                Strucutre = new StructureItem() {
                    CheckList = new CheckList() {
                        Checks = new List<Check>
                        {
                            new Check { NumberAsInt = "149" },
                            new Check { NumberAsInt = "260" },
                            new Check { NumberAsInt = null }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new ProductCrp {
                Strucutre = new StructureItem() {
                    CheckList = new CheckList() {
                        Checks = new List<Check>
                        {
                            new Check { NumberAsInt = "261" },
                            new Check { NumberAsInt = "150" },
                            new Check { NumberAsInt = "260" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        string[] numbers = { "149" };
```

LINQ:

```
        foreach (var item in product)
        {
            item.Strucutre.CheckList.Checks = item.Strucutre.CheckList.Checks.Where(w => numbers.Contains(w.NumberAsInt)).Select(w => w);
        }
```

Comment: The issue here is that you're not making a selection, you're updating the actual items.  Is this what you want?  Do you actually want a cloned collection of items with `Checks` set how you want?

Comment: So, what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me - why add those items if you intend filtering them out immediately?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to select ProductCrp  objects which have one of the values from "numbers" in the Checks array? Because if you are trying to get the top level object you could just do a where and drill down in the lambda that you are passing in.

(Providing this is linq to objects). If this is linq to SQL there are a lot more considerations here.

Comment: Is there a reason why `Structure` is inconsistently spelled wrong?

Comment: Can you describe why you appended the trivial `Select` on the end there? That is not *always* the wrong thing to do but it is a bit weird.  What's up with that?

Comment: Yes, the task was precisely in cloning. select to select an object, maybe it can be omitted?

Comment: I filter the data on the basis of a string array, ie there can be more numbers and I need to display those symbols that match, and remove the extra ones

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I managed to make a selection from the complex structure of the object, but only with the help of foreach, how can I avoid this foreach and solve my problem, just using LINQ?

**You do not use LINQ for this purpose.  You are using `foreach` correctly.**

LINQ is for *querying* data.  A `foreach` loop is about *producing a side effect repeatedly*.  The body of your `foreach` is mutating a property of an object; that's an *update* and not a *query*, so *you are doing it right*.  Using LINQ for that is wrong; don't do it.

Answers that say to, for instance, use `ToList` to force iteration of a query with a side effect are **extremely bad style** and result in code which is inefficient, hard to understand, hard to maintain, and works against the purpose of the query operators. NEVER abuse LINQ like that. We have a construct built into the language that means "perform this operation once per collection element", and it is called `foreach`. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
product.ForEach(item => item.Strucutre.CheckList.Checks = item.Strucutre.CheckList.Checks.Where(w => numbers.Contains(w.NumberAsInt)).Select(w => w).ToList());
```

Comment: What is the function of the `ToList` in this?

Comment: Thanks @Eric..Here ToList is not required, I just thought "Checks" property is List<Check> but "Where" return IEnumerable<Check> so I just used ToList to convert it to List<Check>. Making "Check" property to IEnumerable<Check> will avoid ToList.